# JavaScript, HTML: How can I disable the Shift Key (specially when combined with other keys to create special characters)?

Tags: javascript, regex, calculator, shift, preventdefault

https://ysuran92.github.io/calculator-project/index

I have a calculator project, or something like that. It's made in HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
Now, in my JS file there is some code to prevent characters like letters from showing up in the calculator's display. The only thing I can't get my head around is how to "disable" Shift+(0-9).
Here is some code:

```
  // let regEx = /^\s*([-+]?)(\d+)(?:\s*([-+*\/])\s*((?:\s[-+])?\d+)\s*)+$/;

document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
 if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.code == "NumpadEnter") {
     calc.value = eval(calc.value);
 } else if (event.keyCode == 46) {
     calc.value = "";
 } else if (event.keyCode == 8) {
     back();
 } else if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
     calc.value += event.key;
 } else if (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) {
     calc.value += event.key;
 } else if (
     event.keyCode == 107 ||
     event.keyCode == 109 ||
     event.keyCode == 106 ||
     event.keyCode == 111 ||
     event.keyCode == 190 ||
     event.keyCode == 110
  ) {
      calc.value += event.key;
  }
 });
```

As you may notice, I've already tried RegEx (which didn't work, probably because I don't know anything about it) and I've also tried event.preventDefault().
Any tips or comments will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably better off with an allowed list than a block list. Mobile users don't have to hit Shift, and I could always paste in a special character.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the recommendation that was given to you to use a regexp is to actually test `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`.
You don't have to test for the keyboard key that was pressed, but simply which value you're going to add into your string. This is better, because this is not dependent on the keyboard of the user.

Here is a naive way of doing that:

```js
if (['0', '1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'].includes(e.key)) {
  console.log('I am a number');
}
```

Regexps are more complex, but allow you to write this is a way more condensed form:

```js
if (e.key.match(/[0-9]/)) {
  console.log('I am a number');
}
```

The regexp you have doesn't only allow numbers though.
It can be used to validate that a given expression is correct, e.g. `1 * 2 / -3`. This [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/69lfXV/3) could help you understand it a bit more.